# How to check if a given link is valid?

Tags: ios, hyperlink

I wanted to know if it was possible to check if a link is working/ ok in iOS. Can anyone kindly help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a given URL? What about logins, POSTs, intranets?

Comment: its just some video links. want to check if they are valid before sending them to the custom video player.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSMutableURLRequest and then setHTTPMethod to HEAD.  Pass that to an NSURLConnection.  You can then get the HTTP status code which will let you know if it's a good link or a 404.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: NSURLConnection will run asynchronously unless you explicitly tell it not to, so it won't lock up your UI.  But if your app depends on that information to proceed, yes, it will slow you down. As long as the server is online and the user is on a decent connection it shouldn't be very long though.  A HEAD request is very small.